# Problem to login to sftp server via phpseclib3

Tags: authentication, private-key, phpseclib

I have the issue, that I can't login to a SFTP using a private key with phpseclib3.
On the console with sftp it works fine.
The SFTP Server is an AWS_SFTP_1.1.
Last request - response from the phpseclib3 log:

```
-> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.7201, network: 0.0001s)
00000000  00:00:00:03:4c:4d:58:00:00:00:0e:73:73:68:2d:63  ....LMX....ssh-c
00000010  6f:6e:6e:65:63:74:69:6f:6e:00:00:00:09:70:75:62  onnection....pub
00000020  6c:69:63:6b:65:79:00:00:00:00:0c:72:73:61:2d:73  lickey.....rsa-s
00000030  68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:00:00:02:17:00:00:00:07:73  ha2-256........s
00000040  73:68:2d:72:73:61:00:00:00:03:01:00:01:00:00:02  sh-rsa..........
00000050  01:00:bf:98:b0:16:78:04:65:6a:ff:62:67:c9:2d:c3  ......x.ej.bg.-.
00000060  39:48:db:31:e8:2c:aa:d8:d5:a7:f3:7d:c2:f4:d2:dc  9H.1.,.....}....
00000070  e0:72:2e:c4:2c:ea:ef:b1:ad:ad:b9:63:d0:51:6d:ea  .r..,......c.Qm.
00000080  c3:d6:97:e5:db:1a:7b:29:3e:52:f0:c8:be:f6:ce:7f  ......{)>R......
00000090  8e:5e:97:f5:4e:1c:09:75:be:ec:77:a8:54:c7:92:e4  .^..N..u..w.T...
000000a0  58:be:eb:98:df:7b:fa:d6:1c:fc:0c:b7:7e:ac:20:27  X....{......~. '
000000b0  9b:70:f1:a0:31:9c:51:dc:3c:d5:63:f0:44:59:d8:d3  .p..1.Q...c.DY..
000000c0  cf:65:62:cd:fb:40:b3:f5:64:73:da:f3:70:95:18:ed  .eb..@..ds..p...
000000d0  1c:9b:84:9a:c4:32:d1:96:ab:06:27:19:1b:f1:2d:95  .....2....'...-.
000000e0  85:62:5e:7e:ef:49:73:6b:8a:cb:ab:b8:65:06:73:93  .b^~.Isk....e.s.
000000f0  fb:10:b0:03:98:06:57:e8:e9:d0:6f:1f:32:46:9b:05  ......W...o.2F..
00000100  3e:53:7a:9b:86:71:14:b7:d3:38:af:25:8b:7b:52:e3  >Sz..q...8.%.{R.
00000110  c3:97:79:09:fe:09:04:11:f5:c4:e6:27:e9:67:a5:17  ..y........'.g..
00000120  59:de:6e:dd:a8:90:ec:de:05:2d:0f:ac:70:0b:b6:63  Y.n......-..p..c
00000130  3a:46:76:86:c9:29:b3:0e:81:c4:3d:9a:2d:84:27:ba  :Fv..)....=.-.'.
00000140  e4:0c:81:13:3f:2d:69:94:e7:92:b5:94:cf:75:9d:d4  ....?-i......u..
00000150  0e:42:fb:a3:e3:5e:85:81:60:5c:e6:fe:bb:40:2c:10  .B...^..`\...@,.
00000160  a0:1d:84:e4:ab:4c:ea:8a:32:ab:fe:b8:83:86:9d:90  .....L..2.......
00000170  b0:20:1d:ee:fa:19:3f:c2:01:8d:77:14:ff:4c:23:8e  . ....?...w..L#.
00000180  a7:8d:29:da:bc:95:b8:c3:e2:48:4e:fa:d5:92:65:07  ..)......HN...e.
00000190  df:32:86:b0:ad:89:a5:22:39:78:79:c9:5f:53:85:20  .2....."9xy._S. 
000001a0  6e:cf:5d:34:4d:1f:77:6f:af:df:07:ba:a7:d1:9c:ac  n.]4M.wo........
000001b0  be:9c:5e:0a:ad:4e:eb:82:e4:99:a4:2a:4a:7f:76:d0  ..^..N.....*J.v.
000001c0  3c:38:12:95:6c:e4:6f:7d:50:7c:de:ae:0f:82:0e:0c  .8..l.o}P|......
000001d0  7c:fc:b3:b9:73:a8:c7:c7:ab:5d:1e:e7:51:3b:5e:22  |...s....]..Q;^"
000001e0  fe:cb:e1:61:96:74:94:7c:fd:75:93:00:fd:27:24:a1  ...a.t.|.u...'$.
000001f0  44:84:42:e9:25:ac:ae:8c:a5:45:ce:de:c4:cd:2e:7d  D.B.%....E.....}
00000200  b1:03:56:72:3d:af:44:aa:fc:2d:20:bc:57:f4:da:c2  ..Vr=.D..- .W...
00000210  c5:b0:25:5b:05:0e:04:d5:3a:7a:c3:c3:2c:cc:8a:e0  ..%[....:z..,...
00000220  a6:c5:27:ca:d6:ae:20:62:8d:73:21:6c:b8:77:b9:de  ..'... b.s!l.w..
00000230  7b:f8:61:3f:ca:10:c4:f0:e6:fe:0c:45:d0:0c:68:d1  {.a?.......E..h.
00000240  2a:5a:db:fa:c3:65:da:24:91:4f:b4:9c:a1:b0:2d:fa  *Z...e.$.O....-.
00000250  51:d9                                            Q.

<- UNKNOWN (60) (since last: 0.0515, network: 0.0427s)
00000000  00:00:00:0c:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36  ....rsa-sha2-256
00000010  00:00:02:17:00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00  ........ssh-rsa.
00000020  00:00:03:01:00:01:00:00:02:01:00:bf:98:b0:16:78  ...............x
00000030  04:65:6a:ff:62:67:c9:2d:c3:39:48:db:31:e8:2c:aa  .ej.bg.-.9H.1.,.
00000040  d8:d5:a7:f3:7d:c2:f4:d2:dc:e0:72:2e:c4:2c:ea:ef  ....}.....r..,..
00000050  b1:ad:ad:b9:63:d0:51:6d:ea:c3:d6:97:e5:db:1a:7b  ....c.Qm.......{
00000060  29:3e:52:f0:c8:be:f6:ce:7f:8e:5e:97:f5:4e:1c:09  )>R.......^..N..
00000070  75:be:ec:77:a8:54:c7:92:e4:58:be:eb:98:df:7b:fa  u..w.T...X....{.
00000080  d6:1c:fc:0c:b7:7e:ac:20:27:9b:70:f1:a0:31:9c:51  .....~. '.p..1.Q
00000090  dc:3c:d5:63:f0:44:59:d8:d3:cf:65:62:cd:fb:40:b3  ...c.DY...eb..@.
000000a0  f5:64:73:da:f3:70:95:18:ed:1c:9b:84:9a:c4:32:d1  .ds..p........2.
000000b0  96:ab:06:27:19:1b:f1:2d:95:85:62:5e:7e:ef:49:73  ...'...-..b^~.Is
000000c0  6b:8a:cb:ab:b8:65:06:73:93:fb:10:b0:03:98:06:57  k....e.s.......W
000000d0  e8:e9:d0:6f:1f:32:46:9b:05:3e:53:7a:9b:86:71:14  ...o.2F..>Sz..q.
000000e0  b7:d3:38:af:25:8b:7b:52:e3:c3:97:79:09:fe:09:04  ..8.%.{R...y....
000000f0  11:f5:c4:e6:27:e9:67:a5:17:59:de:6e:dd:a8:90:ec  ....'.g..Y.n....
00000100  de:05:2d:0f:ac:70:0b:b6:63:3a:46:76:86:c9:29:b3  ..-..p..c:Fv..).
00000110  0e:81:c4:3d:9a:2d:84:27:ba:e4:0c:81:13:3f:2d:69  ...=.-.'.....?-i
00000120  94:e7:92:b5:94:cf:75:9d:d4:0e:42:fb:a3:e3:5e:85  ......u...B...^.
00000130  81:60:5c:e6:fe:bb:40:2c:10:a0:1d:84:e4:ab:4c:ea  .`\...@,......L.
00000140  8a:32:ab:fe:b8:83:86:9d:90:b0:20:1d:ee:fa:19:3f  .2........ ....?
00000150  c2:01:8d:77:14:ff:4c:23:8e:a7:8d:29:da:bc:95:b8  ...w..L#...)....
00000160  c3:e2:48:4e:fa:d5:92:65:07:df:32:86:b0:ad:89:a5  ..HN...e..2.....
00000170  22:39:78:79:c9:5f:53:85:20:6e:cf:5d:34:4d:1f:77  "9xy._S. n.]4M.w
00000180  6f:af:df:07:ba:a7:d1:9c:ac:be:9c:5e:0a:ad:4e:eb  o..........^..N.
00000190  82:e4:99:a4:2a:4a:7f:76:d0:3c:38:12:95:6c:e4:6f  ....*J.v..8..l.o
000001a0  7d:50:7c:de:ae:0f:82:0e:0c:7c:fc:b3:b9:73:a8:c7  }P|......|...s..
000001b0  c7:ab:5d:1e:e7:51:3b:5e:22:fe:cb:e1:61:96:74:94  ..]..Q;^"...a.t.
000001c0  7c:fd:75:93:00:fd:27:24:a1:44:84:42:e9:25:ac:ae  |.u...'$.D.B.%..
000001d0  8c:a5:45:ce:de:c4:cd:2e:7d:b1:03:56:72:3d:af:44  ..E.....}..Vr=.D
000001e0  aa:fc:2d:20:bc:57:f4:da:c2:c5:b0:25:5b:05:0e:04  ..- .W.....%[...
000001f0  d5:3a:7a:c3:c3:2c:cc:8a:e0:a6:c5:27:ca:d6:ae:20  .:z..,.....'... 
00000200  62:8d:73:21:6c:b8:77:b9:de:7b:f8:61:3f:ca:10:c4  b.s!l.w..{.a?...
00000210  f0:e6:fe:0c:45:d0:0c:68:d1:2a:5a:db:fa:c3:65:da  ....E..h.*Z...e.
00000220  24:91:4f:b4:9c:a1:b0:2d:fa:51:d9                 $.O....-.Q.
```

From the SFTP verbose log:

```
Authenticated to sftp.someserver.eu (via proxy) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: proc
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: SFTP: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: SFTP: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Connected to sftp.someserver.eu.
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Here is how I've tested:

```
$key  = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents('/keys/ey-rsa'));

$sftp = new SFTP('sftp.someserver.eu', 22);
$sftp->sendIdentificationStringFirst();
$sftp->sendKEXINITFirst();
$sftp->enableDatePreservation();
$sftp->disableQuietMode();
$sftp->login('USER', $key);`
```

And the exception I got:

```
phpseclib3\Exception\ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed prematurely in /opt/xres_code/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:4247
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/xres_code/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(2751): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->send_binary_packet('2\x00\x00\x00\x03USER\x00\x00\x00\x0Essh...')
#1 /opt/xres_code/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(2389): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->privatekey_login('USER', Object(phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA\PrivateKey))
#2 /opt/xres_code/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(2318): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->login_helper('USER', Object(phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA\PrivateKey))
#3 /opt/xres_code/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php(2230): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->sublogin('USER', Object(phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA\PrivateKey))
#4 /opt/xres_code/modules/converter/test.php(42): phpseclib3\Net\SSH2->login('USER', Object(phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA\PrivateKey))
#5 {main}
```

Comment: Sharing the _full_ logs vs the last to and from packet would be helpful. Post them on pastebin.com since they'll take up a lot of space in your post otherwise. Also, it looks like you're doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3)` - try `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` and `echo $ssh->getLog()`. Real time logging is great under certain circumstances but in this case I don't believe it is. Also, what version of phpseclib 3 are you using? I ask because RFC8308 was implemented in 3.0.34 and in lieu of having the full logs or knowing what version you're using I feel like that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I've forgotten to state the phpseclib version. I'm using 3.0.34. This was the first thing I've checked, that I'm up-to-date. Here is the pastbin link [link](https://pastebin.com/7niXtDuM) to the log.

Comment: `-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT (since last: 53.2647, network: 0.0001s)` is a bit red flaggy as is `-> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 51.4503, network: 0.0001s)`. For the first one https://pastebin.com/H73arxbA is what it should be doing. And ya know how much time that should take? Almost none. Even with `BigInteger::setEngine('PHP32');` it still takes less than a second for me. So I guess first, could you post your phpinfo()?

Comment: Also, could you post the output of `$ssh->getAlgorithmsNegotiated()`? Like don't even try to login - just do it after you initialize the SSH2 object. eg. https://pastebin.com/UD22U3cR . It looks like you're using nistp256 but I just want to make sure. But assuming that you are could you try running https://pastebin.com/ETm0J3Jr and tell me how long that takes?

Comment: Hi @neubert and a good day to you. Here is the PHP Info https://pastebin.com/KVqtTzUh - and before you ask, yes in this project we still use PHP 7.3 :-(  Here is the result to `$ssh->getAlgorithmsNegotiated()` https://pastebin.com/uYCC1PNq and the log if needed https://pastebin.com/CZph9tCZ. As for the last https://pastebin.com/ETm0J3Jr  it took 53.485372066498 seconds And thanks again.

Comment: The first pastebin link - https://pastebin.com/KVqtTzUh - has been red flagged by pastebin.com. "_This paste has been deemed potentially harmful. Pastebin took the necessary steps to prevent access on January 9, 2024, 3:22 am CST. If you feel this is an incorrect assessment, please contact us within 14 days to avoid any permanent loss of content._". I tried to contact them but it said "_Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it._" Maybe you can contact them? Or else paste the phpinfo() output elsewhere idk

Comment: And yah - that ~60s processing time is quite long. It shouldn't take that long at all. But if I can get the phpinfo output I can try to reproduce it. Like maybe due to how much time it's taking to do that stuff AWS is simply timing out.

Comment: Let's try it again https://pastebin.com/Vk65ZNB8 to the phpinfo. I've also tried to recover the old, but no response by now.

Comment: it says "_Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation_" and that I can only view it if it belongs to me. I'll come back and check in a few hours but, failing that, I guess my fallback would be to maybe post it on 3v4l.org as commented out code idk

Comment: Okay, lets try it with this: https://share.traso.de/f/b923b5b4f2354b30ba5b/?dl=1